# On INSERT, MariaDB is ignoring missing values that don't have a default value

Tags: insert, default-value, mariadb

Since a short time, my **MariaDB** database ignores missing values for columns that don't have a default value when I perform an *INSERT*. Then it inserts the record anyway.

I have three **MariaDB** databases on different servers which I originally set up with the same settings. While two of them are working the usual way, I may have changed some settings on the other one which now displays this strange behavior.

Anyone got an idea which settings to change to correct it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem for myself. 
Just changed the Server System Variable **SQL_MODE** in the config file **my.ini** from `NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER` to `STRICT_TRANS_TABLES`.